# jQuery validation error messages disturbing my form. (jquery.validate.js)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

Whenever jquery validation error messages appears. It occupies some space and push other fields downwords. I want error messages to be adjust in available space and should not disturb other fields or any other element. following is a jquery validation code that Im using.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

jQuery("#frmQuickAdd").validate({
        errorElement:'div',
        rules: {
            t_style: {
                required: true
            }
        },

        messages: {
            t_style: {
                    required: "Please select therapy style"
            }
       } 
    });

});
```

I tried div,label,span in errorElement:'', still having same problem and error div by default taking class 'error'. Any Idea what CSS I should write ?

Comment: Can you please create example on www.jsfiddle.com and reproduce your problem?

Comment: http://indianhans.org/login/userlogin

You can check over this page see how error messages moving fields downwards.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SxFBF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic solution is to make those error messages absolute positioned.

1. In `ul.ulsignup li` add `margin-bottom: 0;` and `padding-bottom: 10px;`
2. In `ul.ulsignup li .text` add `position: relative;`
3. In `div.error` (or `div div .error`) add `position: absolute;
   bottom: -15px;
   font-size: 10px;`